# MySql update parameters with weird behavior on Visual Studio

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, gridview, parameters, sql-update

Im having a strange problem updating data with mysql on visual studio.
I have a gridview that works well, the edit and delete are both enabled.
The problem is when I try to update, cause I have these 2 behavior above:

1)when I use this code I can normally upgrade the 3 columns in the line 1

```
var SQL = "UPDATE `editora`.`revistas` SET `NUM_EDICAO`= @NUM_EDICAO, `CAPA`= @CAPA, `NIVEL`= @NIVEL WHERE `NUM_EDICAO`= '1';";
```

2)but when I use this code the Sql Commands "ignores" the update on column NUM_EDICAO

```
var SQL = "UPDATE `editora`.`revistas` SET `NUM_EDICAO`= @NUM_EDICAO, `CAPA`= @CAPA, `NIVEL`= @NIVEL WHERE `NUM_EDICAO`= @NUM_EDICAO;";
```

Then I only can change the first Column IF I set a especific value for a line, when I send it by a parameter it is ignored.

Sugestions? Thank you

Comment: How are you binding such parameters?

Comment: Using the object data source wizard 

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
DataObjectTypeName="Editora.Domain.Revista" DeleteMethod="Delete"
InsertMethod="Insert" 
SelectMethod="Select"
TypeName="Editora.DataAccess.Repository" UpdateMethod="Update">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

Comment: show us the code then

Comment: Also you don't need to set the NUM_EDICAO since it's your primary key. I think your problem is due to repeating the same parameter.

Comment: I agree, maybe it's ignoring cause the Num_edicao is the PK

Comment: Try removing it from the SET part, leave it only on the WHERE. Perhaps it'll work. Updating the primary key is NEVER a good idea

Comment: Thank you. It really was Pk item

Comment: I'll add it as an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to update `NUM_EDICAO` as it's your primary key.

```
var SQL = "UPDATE `editora`.`revistas` SET `CAPA`= @CAPA, `NIVEL`= @NIVEL WHERE `NUM_EDICAO`= @NUM_EDICAO;";
```

Removing it from the `UPDATE` will work.